# How to create a schedule for SelfControl app

Tags: macos, applescript, selfcontrol

I want to block my blacklist Mon-Fri 6am-12pm and 1pm-5pm (closely related to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/264332/how-can-i-get-selfcontrol-to-always-run)), but I don't know enough about Applescript to know how to set up a schedule.

Any ideas for how to achieve this?

I am not committed to using SelfControl, either, if anyone knows a simpler (free) way to do this.

Comment: check here http://kylehalladay.com/blog/tutorial/bestof/2014/01/06/Hacking-My-Attention-Span.html

Comment: That's a useful link, but I would never want to hardcode my password in a script like that. Can you not get the password from the keychain?

Answer (score 4):

I have created a small schedule utility for SelfControl:
https://github.com/andreasgrill/auto-selfcontrol